# PicklingError : Can't pickle <function> <lambda> at 0x0000026C13C94430> : it's not found as __main__.<lambda>

Tags: python, machine-learning, lambda, scikit-learn, joblib

I have used CountVectorizer() on following data
It was not considering single letter words so I used lambda in vectorizer

```
data = ['E', 'C', 'Employee', 'Child']

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda txt: txt.split())
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```

But when I am trying to dump model in joblib file

```
dump({'RandomForestClassifier':rfc, 'vectorizer':vectorizer}, 'model_rfc.joblib', compress=1)
```

its giving picklingError

```
PicklingError : Can't pickle <function> <lambda> at 0x0000026C13C94430> : it's not found as __main__.<lambda>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please make your question fully reproducible, by including the joblib dump code and the *full* error trace (not in the comments, edit & update your post).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a lambda function in your `CountVectorizer` and lambdas can't be pickled, hence the pickling error. To circumvent this, define your tokenization function prior to initializing the vectorizer. For example, define your tokenization function:

```
def tokenizer(txt): 
    
    """ whitespace tokenization """
    
    return txt.split()
```

And pass it as a parameter:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

You should be able pickle without any issues after following these steps.